# How not to see the output in the console when adding a new column in a table?

Tags: dataset, data

I have a data table called td and it contains 14k obs and 5k variables.
When I run the command

`td[,fv_mc2:=1]`

I also get the whole data table as output in my console, which floods my console. Any ideas how to fix it ? (It might also be a setting in R, but I am not aware of it.

Comment: I fixed it by updating my R version !

Answer (score 2):

R by default returns the updated dataframe to console.You can assign it to variable by avoiding it.

```
td <- td[,fv_mc2:=1]
```

By this way you can avoid the console of 14k data.